# Casting generics list in Java

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I found a weird situation when casting generics. I run this code:

```
class A { }

class B { }

public class Program {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<A> listA = new ArrayList<A>();
        List<?> list = listA;
        ((List<B>)list).add(new B());

        for (Object item : listA) {
            System.out.println(item.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

It compiles very well (only with warning but without error) and run without any exception and the output was:

> B@88140ed

How did I do that? I mean why Java allow me to do such thing? 
I added an instance of `B` class to list of `A`s?

It is very bad behaviour of generics. Why it is happening?

BTW, I tried it with Java 7.

**EDIT:**
What surprised me is that Java only notify the problem with warning that every programmer can ignore it. I know that `SuppressWarnings` is bad idea, but why Java didn't denied such behavior with error or exception?

In addition, this warning showed always, if you think that your casting is correct you have no choice but to ignore it. But if you think that is good casting and ignore it but it isn't?

Comment: "It compiles very well" - well yes, because you've explicitly suppressed a warning... You should only do that when you understand the warning you're suppressing, which it looks like you don't in this case.

Comment: I meant without fatal error :). Yes, I know that what the warning tells, but I tried it anyway. I expected to get exception or something like that.

Comment: I think "compiles with warnings (which you've disabled)" is pretty different to "compiles very well". If you only disable warnings you understand, and always make sure you understand any warnings you *do* get, you won't have a problem.

Comment: If you try to use it when object class is not that must be - ClassCastException will be thrown

Comment: You were lucky this time. Or actually you were *not*, if you were lucky you would have got a compilation error that would tell you that you're doing something wrong :)

Comment: Well ... Maybe you should add a line `A item = listA.get(0)` (at the end) and see what happens when you run it. Maybe you then understand the warning better.

Comment: People I know what the warning means. But I don't understand why they didn't shows error instead of warning?

Comment: @nrofis What exactly did you expect? A compilatoin error? If yes, what and where? Or an exception when running the program? If yes, what and where?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose yes I expected to throw a compiler error. Where? when I do casting. The compiler can (or should) know what the type of the instance when using wildcast.

Comment: @nrofis please, can you add to your question that when you remove *@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")* you get the following Warning message "*Type safety: Unchecked cast from List<capture#1-of ?> to List<B>*"

Comment: @nrofis You are casting the variable `list` which is of type `List<?>`. The compiler **does not know** the concrete type with which the list was instantiated. If - on the other hand - you cast the variable `listA` to `List<B>`, you will get a compiler error.

Comment: You should put the SupressWarning at the line you do the declaration.

Comment: Honestly I think that this is should not compile. I think that Java needs to improve their compiler for cases like this because the warning appears even if it safe casting and give too much power to the programmer. In C# this case will not allowed.

Comment: `warning that every programmer can ignore`. it compiles and run. why should there be any thing else but warnings? also, if you choose to ignore warning, that's your problem

Comment: @njzk2 I don't agree with you. Because this warning appears every time you cast a wildcard. You must to ignore it if you think that your casting is correct. But what if you think if the casting is correct but it isn't?

Comment: casting a wildcard must be occasional at most. And at this point the compiler warns you that it can't protect you anymore, and it is now up to you to make sure you did things right.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Every programming language allows you to [shoot yourself into the foot](https://www.google.com/search?q=shoot%20yourself%20in%20the%20foot%20programming).

In this case, Java is in a dilemma: It could keep the generics information in the bytecode and break millions of lines of existing code or silently drop the generics information after the compiler has do it's utmost to check and keep backward compatibility.

The Java team decided for the latter and introduced Type Erasure - [which has its flaws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Problems_with_type_erasure). But if they had broken millions of perfectly fine (if type-wise incomplete) lines of Java code, people would have shown up with pitchforks and burning torches ...

Comment: So why the compiler show me only warning and not check the types more thoroughly and show error instead?

Comment: Your example is simple, and everyone can look at it and spot the error. However, compiler writers can't just say "lets just error on some easy-for-humans-to-locate mistakes"; either they have a general answer, or, if they don't, they just output a warning. Implementing a true general answer would be too hard (and break lots of existing code). So they went for the "lets just warn that it might be wrong" approach.

Comment: "people would have shown up with pitchforks and burning torches"... Then why didn't they show up when firmly type-safe generics were added to C#? =)

Comment: @nrofis: A compiler doesn't come with a brain - bring your own. In pre-generics Java, people sometimes tried to put different types of objects into lists. This isn't an error; it can work if you're very, very, **very** careful. It was "clever coding" which saved memory or tried to avoid GC. In the meantime, most people realized that this is bad and stopped it.

Comment: @Mints97: I'm not sure. My guess is that they didn't have the same amount of legacy code, or maybe they didn't care. And let's not forget that software developers on Windows are more ma...um...lenient on average ;-)

Comment: @Mints97: because they were added with *other* compatibility quirks, so the old code *does* still work.

Comment: @Holger: why couldn't Java have added such quirks too, then? =)

Comment: @Mints97: They *could* have done it this way, if loosing Java’s biggest value, the amount of available 3rd party libraries, doesn’t matter. The way Generics were introduced allowed to use existing (not adapted) libraries even inside application that use Generics. You are assuming that C#’s solution is better by looking at a single, possibly overrated, property. Not having full *variance* might hurt much more. Further, having a real enforced Generic type system would imply that even simple things like `Collections.emptyList()` don’t work; it would require a new instance for each type parameter.

Comment: @Mints97 C# didn't add generics to existing classes, so it's got a whole pile of classes that nobody uses anymore (i.e. the old collections like ArrayList).

Comment: @Holger and Aaron - I don't buy this argument, although it's written in JLS and repeated by Bloch etc. We can have both reification and raw type. I don't see how adding generic type info in an object hurts binary compatibility with older libraries. My conspiracy theory is that Sun didn't have enough resource and time to push out Java5; so they find PR excuses to justify erasure as a feature instead of a flaw.

Comment: @bayou.io: it seems, you changed the topic. There is a difference between an implementation which enforces type safety of Generics and an implementation which just adds type information to each instantiation. The latter does indeed not harm compatibility, but I still see the performance impact. As hinted, what is the type of `Collections.emptyList()` or `Function.identity()`? A full reification would require a distinct instance of a distinct type for each site using it with different type arguments. And that’s spreading: `map.entrySet().iterator().next().getReifiedType()` returns *what*?

Comment: @Holger - I accept the performance argument. But the official `compatibility` argument is very fishy to me. I'm seeking if anyone could elaborate and justify the official argument - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/java-lang-fans/jn6187fWEo8

Comment: @bayou.io: I think you should ask a new question for this :-)

Comment: @bayou.io: If generic types were mandatory, you couldn't compile legacy code anymore. As it is, you can compile it (and you get byte code that works) at the cost of lots of generics warnings. There is probably also trouble when you have code paths that go generics -> legacy -> generics -> legacy (callbacks and the like) or when you override method return types.

Comment: @AaronDigulla - to ask an opinionated question on stackoverflow? I'm been scared by mods enough :)

Comment: @bayou.io: That's not opinonated; just ask what in Java would specifically break if they would compile the generics information into the byte code/types.

Answer (score 7):

You've defeated the Java compile-time checks through your casting and suppression of warnings.

Note that thanks to [type-erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) the list you've created is (under the covers) a simple type-unaware list, and contains no *run-time* checks or assertions as to what you're putting into it.

Answer (score 3):

> It is very bad behaviour of generics. Why it is happening?

Because you forced it to happen with the cast, and then made sure that the warnings would be ignored too with your `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

It's your fault, not the generics mechanism's.

Comment: Well, erasure *is* a pretty nasty limitation of Java generics, and one which I wish didn't exist. I agree that the OP shouldn't suppress warnings without understanding them though.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, you have circumvented java's type safety.

I will add that your code doesn't explode because your code doesn't require the elements to be anything in particular (just Object). However, had you coded this:

```
for (A item : listA) { /* whatever */ }
```

It would have compiled, but would have thrown a ClassCastException at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the code for safer:

```
for (A item : listA) {/* your code here */}
```

Or

```
for (Object item : listA) {
                if (item instanceof A) {for (A item : listA) {/* your code here*/}
}
```

Even if you modify the code as given below, you will get the ClassCastException:

```
for (Object item : listA) {
   System.out.println(((A)item).toString()); // Here you will get ClassCastException
}
```